# Como enviar de mais de uma id AJAX - PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

No caso abaixo eu estou enviando os dados da ID: id_motor...
E seu euquiser enviar outra ID junto, tipo a id_motor e a id_modelo, como eu faria?

```js
  $(function(){
   $('#id_motor').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() ) {
     $('#id_ano').hide();
     $('.carregando').show();
     $.getJSON('sub_ano.php?search=',{id_motor: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '<option value="">Escolha o Ano</option>'; 
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
       options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].ano + '</option>';
      } 
      $('#id_ano').html(options).show();
      $('.carregando').hide();
     });
    } else {
     $('#id_ano').html('<option value="">– Escolha o Ano –</option>');
    }
   });
  });
```

Do outro lado estou recuperando como:

$id_motor = $_REQUEST['id_motor'];

e teria que recuperar mais um, exemplo:

$id_motor = $_REQUEST['id_motor'];

$id_modelo = $_REQUEST['id_modelo'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizo o array "data" para passar os parâmetros utilizando jquery ajax:

```
$('#id_motor').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'sub_ano.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json', //espera o retorno em json
        data: {
            //aqui você passa quantos parametros precisar
            id_motor: $("#meuMotor").val(), //id do campo id_motor
            id_outro : $("#outro_id").val(), // id do campo outro_id
        },
        success: function(j){
            var options = '<option value="">Escolha o Ano</option>';    
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].ano + '</option>';
            }   
            $('#id_ano').html(options).show();
            $('.carregando').hide();
        },
        error: function(){
            Alert("Erro ao processar requisição"); //deu algum erro na requisição
        }

    }); //fim do ajax

});
```